# How to fix pip after running it with sudo?

Tags: python, pip

So I ran `pip` with `sudo`, and now when I try to run it again it shows me:

```
no module named pip._internal
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `pip` as `root` ("with `sudo`"), you've had `pip` save information, as `root`, somewhere in your `$HOME` directory tree. This is a disadvantage of using `sudo`.

You can find all the files under `$HOME` that are not owned by you with:

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print | xargs ls -ld
```

And, if you want to change them all back to your ownership:

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print | xargs sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

will do it.

Comment: To prevent this in the future, you can use `sudo -i pip` instead.